# htaccess redirect not working properly

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to accomplish the following but my code is not working
1) I want to do either non-www to www or www to non-www
2) desktop users should be redirected to example.com/homepage
3) remove or hide /homepage from url
4) redirect mobile users to example.com/m

here is my code, it's not working, too many problems to list, but off the top of my head, I can think of 2 problems that I encountered: "cannot open page because too many redirects occurred" and mobile users are taken to /homepage instead of /m

```
# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /homepage [L]


RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^$ homepage/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ homepage/$1 


RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(ip(ad|od|hone)|blackberry|iemobile|android).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/.*
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com/m [R=301,L]
```

Please help me, I am so frustrated, what am I supposed to change about this code to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately im no genious with regex or redirects in htacces but I have gotten similar code to work myself.

It does sound like your code is getting stuck in a redirect loop and the browser is stopping it from continuing. 
I know thats not a complete answer but Hopefully that helps you make more sense of the code atleast a little.

Hopefully someone else can chime in otherwise i can dig up the code that is working when im on the computer and hopefully give you a better response.

-Sent from my cell

Answer (score 0):

The www/non-www is fine.

For the homepage stuff, you need to do two things: make sure what you're rewriting into the homepage directory actually exists (otherwise you get a 500 server error) and exclude mobile user agents.

So this stuff:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /homepage [L]


RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^$ homepage/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ homepage/$1
```

Needs to look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(ip(ad|od|hone)|blackberry|iemobile|android).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/homepage%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/homepage%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ homepage/$1 [L]
```

Comment: still does not work. on desktop, it will go to root, it will not go to /homepage and on mobile, page doesn't load, it says cannot load because server stopped responding.